# grepping array elements from a tcl file

Tags: tcl

I have something like below in a tcl file.

```
array set myports {
a
b
c
d
e
}

array set myports {
g
h
i
j
K
l
}
```

How to do a simple grep on the file and print the elements in the array ?

Comment: Doesn't `array set` create an *associative* array out of *pairs* of elements anyhow? So the first assignment is invalid (since it has an odd number of list elements) I think, while the second would produce an array with elements like `myports(g) = h` and so on. What exactly is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @sanjoy, please describe your situation in more detail. Why does a shell script need to know about some values in a Tcl file?

Answer (score 0):

How about this awk command:

```
awk '/array set myports {/ {for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i == "}") {break} else {printf("%s ", $i)}}} END {printf("\n")}' test.in
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You'll need to count open/close braces: `array set foo { { bar baz } { hello world } }`  creates an associative array mapping the key " bar baz " to the value " hello world "

Answer (score 0):

If it's OK to *execute* the Tcl file, then you could run a little wrapper Tcl script to extract the values:

```
$ cat file.tcl
array set A { hello world how are you today }

$ values=$( tclsh <<END_TCL
    source file.tcl
    parray A      
END_TCL
)

$ echo "$values"
A(hello) = world
A(how)   = are
A(you)   = today
```